# Check if received bitcoin are in blockchain/not pending without a transaction id

Tags: api, withdrawal, transaction-malleability, bitstamp

I want to use the [Bitstamp](http://www.bitstamp.net) exchanger API to buy Bitcoin automatically. But then I see the API does not give me back a transaction-ID (txn id) if I do a withdrawal of Bitcoin to my wallet.

If the exchanger gives me no transaction-ID when I start a withdrawal, how can I check that everything is fine? Normally, I think, you wait for x confirmations of the transaction, but the exchanger won't provide it.

Is it enough to check the receipt of the Bitcoin amount in a unique account or will I be assailable for transaction malleability, double spending or similar? Is there a reason why the exchanger doesn't give back a txn-id? Because I saw other exchangers which do the same.

I am grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

It's not how all exchanges are handling this.

Bitstamp is sending bitcoins in batch transactions. That means it is sending your bitcoins to your address and other users' bitcoins to their address *in the same transaction*.

That means that bitstamp does not yet know the TxId when you submit your withdrawal request.

That is the why.

As for how to solve it, yes you can get a new address for each withdrawal and wait for it to get confirmations. You will not be *assailable for transaction malleability, double spending or similar* if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess exchanger does not give you txid because of transaction malleability. Someone can change this id.

It is enough to check the receipt of the Bitcoin amount in a unique account. Third party cannot change this fact. The only thing that third party can change in original transaction - tx id.